# Using ccache with clang 5 causes different results from just clang5

Tags: clang++, ccache

So with this contrived bit of code - compiling with clang works just fine, but when ccache is used extra warnings/errors appear - I thought ccache is supposed to transparently pass these through. This is ccache 3.1.6 on CentOS 6 from epel repo - upgrading is not an option as this is production environment.

```
#include <byteswap.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    auto j = bswap_32(i);
    (void)j;

    return 0;
}
```

So example 1 with unused include path gives no errors:

```
clang++ -Wno-c++98-compat -Wall -Werror -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/include -c ccache.cpp
```

But with ccache I get:

```
ccache clang++ -Wno-c++98-compat -Wall -Werror -std=c++17 -I/usr/include/xmlib -c ccache.cpp 
clang-5.0: error: argument unused during compilation: '-I /usr/include/xmlib' [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Example 2 without the extra include works just fine:

```
clang++ -Wno-c++98-compat -Wall -Werror -std=c++17  -c ccache.cpp
```

And with ccache

```
cache clang++ -Wno-c++98-compat -Wall -Werror -std=c++17  -c ccache.cpp 
ccache.cpp:6:32: error: ISO C++17 does not allow 'register' storage class specifier [-Wregister]
    auto j = (__extension__ ({ register unsigned int __v, __x = (i); if (__builtin_constant_p (__x)) __v = ((((__x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | (((__x) & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) | (((__x) & 0x0000ff00) << 8) | (((__x) & 0x000000ff) << 24)); else __asm__ ("bswap %0" : "=r" (__v) : "0" (__x)); __v; }));
                               ^~~~~~~~~
ccache.cpp:6:32: error: ISO C++17 does not allow 'register' storage class specifier [-Wregister]
    auto j = (__extension__ ({ register unsigned int __v, __x = (i); if (__builtin_constant_p (__x)) __v = ((((__x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | (((__x) & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) | (((__x) & 0x0000ff00) << 8) | (((__x) & 0x000000ff) << 24)); else __asm__ ("bswap %0" : "=r" (__v) : "0" (__x)); __v; }));
                                   ^~~~~~~~~
    2 errors generated.
```

Why does using ccache change the results?

Comment: In your first example you include `/usr/local/include` for the straight `clang`  compilation, but `/usr/local/xmlib` for the `ccache clang` invocation, so the commands are not the same. Was that intentional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is that by default, `ccache` will pre-process the file (run the C-preprocessor on it) to get a single pre-processed translation unit which it uses to check its cache. Then, for efficiency's sake, if it "misses" in its cache and has to compile the file, it passes the pre-processed file directly to `clang`, telling `clang` not to run the pre-processor, only the compiler (e.g., by giving it the extension `.i`).

Since it is not running the pre-processor, `-I` arguments are inherently ignored, and this is what `clang` is complaining about. `gcc` is not as picky about this so it doesn't pose a problem there.

In `ccache` 3.2, fixes have been made and this problem goes away based on my local testing.

If you're stuck on 3.1, you can `export CCACHE_CPP2=yes` in your environment, which tells `ccache` to not bother with the above optimization and just pass the original C or C++ file into `clang`. How much performance this costs depends on the cost of pre-processing versus compilation.

I experienced this issue on TravisCI (which has an old 3.1 version of `ccache`) and this fixed it for me.

Your compilation error is probably rooted in the same reason: `clang` probably ignores errors in some or all system headers like `<byteswap.h>` but not in "user code". Since `ccache` passes it a big pre-processd blob, it all looks like user-code to clang.

This [three part blog series](http://peter.eisentraut.org/blog/2014/12/01/ccache-and-clang-part-3/) explains this issue in more detail and contains links to relevant `ccache` bugs and discussion.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I had assumed that it ccache was maybe taking a digest of the source and then passing that through. I'll try compiling tomorrow a pre-processed version - but I bet you have the answer it makes total sense

Comment: It does take a digest of the source: that's how it looks up in its cache, but for compilation it passes through the pre-processed source. I was able to reproduce the problem locally: try passing a `*.i` file to clang with any `-I` argument and it will fail in the same way.

Comment: Totally forget about this!